# Get selected radio item true OR false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get weather the radio button is selected or not by Jquery, but it always returns me false even if the id is checked

So far i tried this:

```
$("#opt_34709").prop('checked');
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="opt_34709" value="119740" name="options[34709][]">
```

Comment: You'll have to post more code; that is in fact how you check the "checked" property and yes it does work when it's employed properly.

Comment: Did you include/load jQuery? Did it load properly? Are you sure you're not checking the radio too early (are you using ondomready)?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the javascript console?  Also, when in your codes flow of logic are you checking the radio?

Comment: when i do this $("#opt_34709").val(); it returns me accurate value which is 119740 but not tell me if its true or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this little fiddle I provided two more radio button options. Each time you click on one of the radio buttons you will be shown the value of the **first** radio button. I hope this helps.

```js
$(':radio').click(function(){
  console.log($("#opt_34709").prop('checked'))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="opt_34709" value="119740" name="options[34709][]">09<br>
<input type="radio" id="opt_34710" value="119741" name="options[34709][]">10<br>
<input type="radio" id="opt_34711" value="119742" name="options[34709][]">11
```